# Restore vim runtime path?

Tags: vim

So I ran `:set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/node` inside vim but decided I don't actually like this bundle and want to restore my runtime path. Does anybody know how I'd do this?

Comment: Do you know what it was before / what the default is?  If so can you use the same command to update it with your desired path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:set runtimepath-=~/.vim/bundle/node` to remove that path from the runtimepath option. See `:help :set-=` for more details.

In order to restore runtimepath, or any other option, to its default value you can use `:set runtimepath&` as described in `:help :set-default`.